# zsh - check arguments of a command before executing it

Tags: command-line, zsh

*Question:* Is there an easy way how I can teach `zsh` to check the command line before executing it? I know that I can completely wrap a specific program with an extra script, but this is not what I want to do.

*Example:*
Using tab completion, it could happen to me easily, that I overwrite my input file by calling `gcc` wrongly e.g.

```
gcc test.c -o test.c
```

instead of

```
gcc test.c -o test
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could redefine the `accept-line` `zle` widget to do all the checks you want like:

```
accept-line() {
  if [[ $BUFFER =~ '^gcc.*-o\s*\S*\.c\b' ]]; then
    zle -M 'I will not do that!'
  else
    zle .$WIDGET "$@"
  fi
}
zle -N accept-line
```